# Fick surface plot_quaternions

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a function:

```
def Fick_surface(data1,s):
    return s*(data1[1]*data1[2]/data1[0])
```

where

```
data1 = np.array([q0, q2, q3, q1])
```

I know the values of q0,q2 and q3 and I fitted the data I have with a surface so that I get a q1_guess_updated. The 3D space would have q1_guess_updated as x axis, q2 as y and q3 as z. The problem is that if I represent the surface with the data I have, it looks very bad. I wanted to try an interpolation, but q0 gets in the way.

```
X=q1_guess_updated
Y,Z=np.meshgrid(ys,zs)
ax1.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
```

Do you have any suggestion on how I could get more points from q2 and q3, at the same time getting the corresponding points in q0 (that would go in the equation) and q1_guess_updated (which instead goes in the graph together with q2 and q3)? Do you think it is possible? I would like to avoid to fix a q0 value and get subplots, since the I have many values of q0.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're talking about in most of this question. Is the `data1` array supposed to be a quaternion (a 4D imaginary number), or is it just a normal value in 4D space? What in the word is `q1_guess_updated`? Why are you trying to graph a 4D function in 3D? Can you provide a [mcve] that shows the "very bad" way your graph looks?

Comment: data1 is a quaternion, but I don't mind about the scalar part q0, since I just have to represent in a 3D space the vector with coordinates q1_guess_updated,q2,q3. The q1_guess_updated is just the q1 value I get from the Fick_surface function once I try to fit a series of points I have in the 3d space. These points have coordinates (q1,q2,q3). I cannot upload an image, cause this is my second post.

Comment: I have upvoted your question; you should now have the necessary reputation to upload an image

Comment: ah, sorry, didn't realise this was an old question! xD   Oh well. Anyway, you can now upload images! \o/